# why 'Would' in this sentence?. Why not a simple present

Tags: grammar

Why do we use *would* in the following sentence?. Can we replace the would with "it burns your fingers"

A hot potato is definitely something you don’t want to hold with your bare hands for a long time, because it *would* burn your fingers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A hot potato is definitely something you don’t want to hold with your bare hands for a long time, because it would burn your fingers.

This is a conditional sentence that states a condition that will cause a specific result.  Use of the simple present "it burns" states something  **is** happening now, not might/probably/will happen.  This if/then construction proposes the consequence given the stated condition, not a present action.

"Holding a hot potato too long burns my fingers" is a statement of present action.

"If I hold a hot potato too long, it will/would burn my fingers" is a conditional sentence offering "if this, then that" information.

If a time is set in the conditional, then the present tense would be used:
"When I hold a hot potato too long, it burns my fingers."

Comment: too difficult to understand. could you simplify please?

Comment: Simply, the answer to your question is "no" the present tense "burns" is not used in this conditional sentence.  Use "would" when a condition is given for a result when no time is specified.

Comment: Can you please provide one similar sentence to support your answer. It would be easy for me to get the essence of your answer

Comment: "If you do this, then that would happen.  When you to this, that happens"

Comment: This comment is more useful than the whole answer!. Thanks a ton

Comment: Glad our minds could finally connect.  Sometimes bare bones is all that is needed.